# Why assignment operator overloading is not working?

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading

I have defined class st in C++, it is like predefined string class available in C++;
and it can only do 3 operation as shown in the program.
I have overloaded `=` and `+` operator and with overloaded `=` operator I am copying string literal to object of class.
as the assignment operator is overloaded when i use it with class object the overloaded function should work.
but instead old `=` operator giving error:  `error: conversion from ‘const char [9]’ to non-scalar type ‘st’ requested
  st s1="sfsefseg";`
why overloaded assignment operator working?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class st{
    char *arr;
    int size;
    public:
    st(){
        arr=new char[0];
        size=0;
    }
    void operator=(const char*);
    friend st operator+(st&,st&);
    void display();
};
void st::operator=(const char *ch){
    int i;
    for(i=0;ch[i]!='\0';i++)
    size=i;
    delete [] arr;
    arr=new char[size];
    for(i=0;i<size;i++){
        arr[i]=ch[i];       
    }
    display();
}
st operator+(st &t,st &s){
    st temp;
    temp.size=t.size+s.size;
    temp.arr=new char[temp.size];
    for(int i=0;i<t.size;i++){
        temp.arr[i]=t.arr[i];
    }
    for(int i=0;i<s.size;i++){
        temp.arr[i+t.size]=s.arr[i];
    }
    temp.display();
    return temp;
}
void st::display(){
    if(size==0)
        cout<<"\nEmpty string";
    else{
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
            cout<<arr[i]<<"  ";
    }
}
int main(){
    st s1="sfsefseg";
    st s2="FJHSFK";
    st s3=s1+s2;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: cosnt char[n] != char*

Comment: Read the error carefully: `const char [9]` and `char*`. What qualifier is missing?